# Searching intersection point of two splines in graph

Tags: c#, .net, graph, spline

I am stuck at this point. I am trying to find where two lines in graph intersects. I have 10 points for each spline, but they intersects between this points.

I am using c# graph. (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart2;) 
Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Here is this situation. Points are measured manually so there is minimum posibility that it will intersetcs on this given points.

[image]

Comment: Since you have only 10 points for each curve, it's feasible to check each possible pair of line segments (one from each curve) to see if they intersect. That will only be 100 checks. Do you know how to check if two line segments intersect? If not, [look here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/determine-where-two-lines-intersect-in-c/).

Comment: They do not intersects on this given points. I solved how to check two lines how they intersects but i have Curved lines(respectively 1 curve line and 1 line).

Comment: I'm not saying you should check if they intersect at the endpoints; I'm saying you should check to see if each pair of line segments intersect.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i did not get it. Because it is measurement of transitor, led diode,... I cant use this... Because values would be discarded. If i would do this like you supposed it would make difference 0,5V between point on spline and line intersect.

Comment: What are your actual data? The points I guess. But how __exactly__ do you arrive at the curves you show us? A Graphics method? Which? If you do you could peek into the graphics to find the point with the right color, using semi-tranparent pens..

Comment: Do you have the equations of the line and curve ?

Comment: I insert this points to the graph and I choose type of graph spline. If I am right i think, that ploting this curves it does by calculating the equation of the curve( for example y=x+5). What did you mean by semi-transparent pens?

Comment: I have equation only from line. I dont have from spline.

Comment: Hmm I see. The point of intersection will crucially depend on the *kind* of spline you're using. Cubic? BSpline? If you're not drawing the spline yourself and using a 3rd party method to draw it, then you will likely have difficulty knowing exactly what points the 3rd party is generating.

Comment: This probably won't help, but [have a look here](https://www.particleincell.com/2013/cubic-line-intersection/).

Comment: I guess that calculating spline should be pretty similiar so it maybe not will do so big mess as if I used connection by lines.

Comment: In Winforms you can use the Graphics.DrawCurve method to draw simple spline curves. you could find the intersction by looking at the drawn pixels. What exactly is the 'graph' you use??

Comment: I am using this graph System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart2;
I think I saw this function in this graph, but i still need it to do it automatic .

Comment: Ah. So please call a Chart a Chart ;-) - Well I don't think it has any method that will help and I wonder if the type of spline-curve it uses is even disclosed. But the inspection of the resulting chart pixels will still work as I suggested. The precision will be adaptable by zooming in on the intersection. Still some work to do and probably cleaner to acomplish by drawing the curves into a dedicated bitmap. But of course any non-mathematical solution will be a hack..

Comment: And because this is my Bachelor work I cant afford do it like this

Comment: Well good luck then; but imo your question can't be answered as it stands because it is not well-defined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used least squares theory and polynomial function to represent equation of curve and after that solve the equation. If anybody needs solution just write me.

Answer (score 0):

Refine the splines to the degree of precision you need and then intersect (straight) line pairs, as Matthew suggested. This can be done quite efficient if you chose the right data structure to store the line segments, so that it supports fast range queries (kd-tree perhaps?).

Doing it analytically is going to be really hard, I guess.

Comment: Because it is measurement of transitor, led diode,... I cant use this... Because values would be discarded.

Comment: @dale what do you mean "values would be discarded"?

Comment: That it is important to find this value on spline. If i would do it like you have supposed to connect each point to next point by line, there would be difference e.g. 0,5V. And another calculation with this discarded value(not so much accurate) would mess up final resolve. Difference here 0,5V can make final difference 2V with calculations.

Comment: That's why I suggested refining the spline first - you can always add points to a spline without altering the resulting shape. Now add enough points that the error between spline interpolation and linear interpolation for each point on the spline is low enough.

Alternatively, you can walk through the data in small enough time steps and just compare the voltages at those time steps (if the sign of the difference changes, you've found an intersection).

Comment: I will only get these 10 points. So i will not be able to add more points between this points where these lines intersects.

Comment: I don't mean "add points to the original measurement". I mean "add points to the list of points representing the spline in the function that computes the intersection point". That is possible if you know what kind of spline you're facing (for an example using b-splines look here: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/subdivision.html)

Comment: That is pretty good idea, so i will try find out which i am using